# AJAX - how to get readystate == 3 to fire repeatedly for uploads?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, xmlhttprequest

I have a PHP script which downloads a large file via cURL and reports mid-download progress to the client via output buffering.

```
ob_start();
ob_flush();
flush();

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/big-video-file.mp4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progress');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo 100;
ob_flush();
flush();

function progress($resource,$download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded) {
    if ($download_size > 0) echo round(($downloaded / $download_size) * 100).',';
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

I can then get updates on progress via the client by listening in `onreadystatechange` for `readyState` == 3.

```
let req = new XMLHttpRequest(), ta = document.querySelector('textarea');
req.open('GET', 'curl_progress.php?ajax=1');
req.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (req.readyState == 3) { //we get here repeatedly - yay!
        let spl = req.responseText.split(',');
        ta.value += spl[spl.length-2]+'\n';
    } else if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
        ta.value += 100;
}, false);
req.send();
```

This works great. Don't worry about my string-handling of the latest progress; the point here is `readyState` == 3 happens repeatedly.

**Now, my question: why doesn't this work with upload?**

I adapted the script to do upload instead. Again, the PHP side works fine. I can see it spitting out tracking information via output buffering. Here's the adapted cURL request for upload rather than download:

```
$ch = curl_init($_SESSION['vimeo_upload_url']);
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_INFILE => fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r'),
    CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $_FILES['file']['size'],
    CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true,
    CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION => 'curl_progress',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Tus-Resumable: 1.0.0',
    'Upload-Offset: 0',
    'Content-Type: application/offset+octet-stream'
]);

function curl_progress($resource, $download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded) {
    if ($upload_size > 0) echo round(($uploaded / $upload_size) * 100).',';
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

The upload itself works great - no problem there.

**But on the client the `readyState` == 3 fires only once** - just before the whole thing completes.

```
let req = new XMLHttpRequest(), fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', input.files[0]);
req.open('POST',  '../vimeo_upload.php?action=transfer_file');
req.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (this.readyState == 3) { //we get here only once!
        let spl = this.responseText.split(',');
        console.log(spl[spl.length-2]);
    } else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        console.log(100);
}, false);
```

Does anyone know why this is, i.e. why I can't get it to fire multiple times like it did for downloading?

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong api...for upload opetarions you should use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload

Comment: Your upload algorithm uses a `PATCH` request and `CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true`. I'd guess it has something to do with that. When configuring `CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true` curl tries to perform a `PUT` request, maybe those headers conflict? I'd recommend removing possible unnecessary headers until it (hopefully) works.

Comment: Thanks both. The upload is successful, though. And the output is correct. It's streamed, due to output buffering. It's just that the client isn't reporting multiple `onreadystate` change events. Nonetheless I'll persevere.